# Good git process for feature branches

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

We've been going back and forth in our team about the best process for individual developers to work with feature branches, rebasing, and etc.  The below is what we came up with (with input from some mailing lists) but it seems a little convoluted & has a lot of steps.  There are other SO questions with some answer examples that seem similar and simpler.

Is this a good workflow?  How could it be simplified (if at all) or changed?

```
git checkout develop # all developer work is off of this branch
git pull --rebase # make sure local develop is up-to-date
git checkout -b my-nifty-feature-559876 # create your feature branch; I like to put Pivotal story ID in it for convenience; not required

# do your work, make sure all tests still pass, etc. COMMIT FREQUENTLY
git commit -m "First part of my nifty feature working; now on to the back-end."

# fetch latest remote develop and rebase your local feature branch on this.
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
# Local feature branch now has latest origin/develop code as base

# repeat above 3 frequently as you're working

# when you're done, pull and rebase one last time, make sure tests pass, then final commit with Pivotal comment
git commit -m "It works! [Fixes #559876]" # commit when done. Include comment like that for Pivotal integration
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop

# Local feature branch now has latest origin/develop code as base

git checkout develop # switch back to develop
git pull
git merge my-nifty-feature-559876 # This should be a simple FF merge
git push origin develop # send to github
git branch -d my-nifty-feature-559876 # you can get rid of your feature branch
```

Answer (score -1):

That's pretty much *the* git workflow. Same for just about every other VCS.

`git rebase origin/develop` vs. `git merge origin/develop` is a matter of taste, but the two are basically equivalent in end result. Rebase gives a cleaner history, but merge means you can always roll back to where you were yesterday.

Similarly, sometimes I prefer to do the final merge with `--squash` to keep the main branch history somewhat cleaner.

One little tip that I consider non-optional though: backup before rebase. If you use rebase to rewrite history there is a danger that you can ruin everything and then can't roll back.

```
git branch my-nifty-feature-559876-BACKUP
git rebase origin/develop

# verify everything rebased ok
git branch -D my-nifty-feature-559876-BACKUP
```

Creating a new branch means that you have a copy of the feature branch before the rebase. You can use `reset` to roll back if the rebase goes horribly wrong.

Comment: But you can roll back a rebase, just reset the refs with e.g. `git checkout -B master master@{1}; git checkout -B develop develop@{1}`, done. You've rolled back your rebase.  Check out `man gitrevisions` and `man git reflog`, you can reset refs to anything within at least the last 90 days.

Comment: Yeah, ok, you *can* do that, but my way basically tags it with a friendly name you can find easily.